# Sort by uploadDate on GridFS in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

GridFS store filename and uploadDate by default.  MongoDB Java driver allow you to find by String Id and DBObject query.  How would I find a file by filename, sorted by uploadDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the `GridFS` class in the MongoDB Java driver.  As you mentioned, it has two methods, `.find(DBObject query)` and `.find(String filename)`, which both return a `List<GridFSDBFile>`.

It's probably best to use the `GridFS.find(String filename)` method and do the `uploadDate` sorting on the client side (eg. use `Collections.sort()`).  BTW, you can use the `ObjectID` instead of the `uploadDate`.  Since the `ObjectID` contains the creation time as the most significant bits, the returned files should naturally be sorted by `uploadDate` in ascending order.  The only downside of relying on the `ObjectID` is that it only has seconds precision, so you'll have to sort on the `uploadDate` if you need sub-second precision.

You can `.find()` on the `db.fs.files DBCollection` and apply the `.sort()` method on the resulting `DBCursor` instance, but the sorting should be cheap enough to do on the client side.  Once you receive the sorted `DBCursor`, you can then query `GridFS` for the individual files.  Though, you'd end up having to call `GridFS.find(ObjectID)` individually, which would probably be less efficient.

Comment: Thanks, my current implementation uses Collections.sort().  The lack of sorting function seem to be a limitation on the Java driver, not gridfs/mongodb.